# How to fix "Cannot open / define command" error?

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firedac

My code feeds a combobox based on the selection of another combobox. If a user makes a selection on the first, then the second reads from an SQLite table and populates its list accordingly. It is like combo1 has a list of categories. The combo2 lists entries for each category.

I am getting FireDAC SQLite error saying that I should use `ExecSQL` to insert a new entry. I am using the `ExecSQL` but still getting the same error. The code and error:

```
procedure TTrips.Btn_Add_Place_DB_02Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    newPlace : string;
    newCat: string;
    newPlaceAddress: string;

begin

    newPlace := EditDestinoPlace.Text;
    newCat := Comb_Place_Cat_02.Text;
    newPlaceAddress := EditDestino.Text;

    if (newPlace <> '') AND (newCat <> '')  then
      begin
        Places_Conn.Connected := True;
        Places_Q.Active := True;
        Places_Q.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO Contacts_Places (Place_Cat, Place_Name, Place_Address) VALUES (:newCat, :newPlace, :newPlaceAddress)';
        Places_Q.Params.ParamByName('newPlace').AsString := newPlace;
        Places_Q.Params.ParamByName('newCat').AsString := newCat;
        Places_Q.Params.ParamByName('newPlaceAddress').AsString := newPlaceAddress;
        Places_Q.ExecSQL;
        loadPlaces;
        ShowMessage('The place ' +newPlace+ ' has been added to the list of common places.');
        Places_Q.Close;
        Places_Conn.Connected := False;
        Places_Q.Active := False;
        Comb_Place_Cat_02.ItemIndex := -1;
        Comb_Places_02.ItemIndex := -1;
      end

    else
      begin
        ShowMessage('Category or Place Name is empty.');
      end;
```

[image: FireDAC Error]

I tried in another table. Same problem.

Comment: Normally you shouldn't set the query active. At least not before you have filled out required parameters. Try to remove that line, it might help. ExecSQL will activate/open the query and then run it. Are you sure Places_Q are aware of the DB connection (you have specified it in the query)?
Except from that I can't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: [Do not make screenshots of texts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4299358). Quote the texts instead. You can press `Ctrl+C` on such a dialog window to copy all the text straight to the clipboard.

Comment: Hi @EirikA. Yeap, it worked when I removed the line that set Query active. I thought that active query should be on every time you would use FDQuery control.  Thanks a lot for your precise solution.